# Can Bazel automatically discover which tests to run?

Tags: bazel

My team uses Bazel and what I'd like to do is `bazel test` and have Bazel automatically detect dependencies of modified files, and run all impacted tests. I feel like this should be possible due to the way dependencies are well defined in build and test rules but haven't been able to find anything on the topic.

Is this currently possible?

Answer (score 3):

Bazel indeed provides the declarative dependency infrastructure to do such test selection, but it does not have a full end-to-end solution. Instead, there are thirdparty projects like https://github.com/Tinder/bazel-diff.